# How Jackson deserialize a Input Map object in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have this simple controller that receives a map as input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/providers", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public Map<String, Object> updateProvider(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates,
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return updates;
    }
```

and I have this property configured in Spring Boot in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_empty
```

Then, if I make a *PATCH* request with following JSON object.

```
{
    "name":"frndo",
    "lastname":""
}
```

The content of result in the *RESPONSE* is:

```
{
  "name":"frndo"
}
```

But the content of input in the *REQUEST* is:

```
{
    "name":"frndo",
    "lastname":""
}
```

My question is, Why the content in the *REQUEST* is different in the *RESPONSE* if to serialize the Map object you have a global configuration like:

`spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_empty`

Precisely why when `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates` arrives have the `name` and `lastname` fields if `lastname` is empty?.

In the *RESPONSE* you can see the effect of the configuration but in the *REQUEST* is not seen. What is the explanation of this, if the mapper had to convert the JSON to a java object, and in that process the global configuration had to be applied?

I expected to have the same content in the *REQUEST* and the *RESPONSE*

Many thanks!

Comment: That property is only used during serialization i.e. converting Java object to JSON. So why do you think it would affect the request where the opposite i.e. deserialization is happening?

Comment: OK, That's my question, I thought it was used both for serialization and for deserialization. Are you sure of this?

Comment: See [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) : "Enumeration used with JsonInclude to define which properties of Java Beans are to be included in serialization. ". That is what this property represents. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005703/jackson-annotations-difference-between-jsonignorepropertiesignoreunknown-true)

Comment: OK, you can place your answer, to help others who have the same question. Thanks!